# LDAP implementation in ALM, issue with existing users having DB authentication

Tags: ldap, openldap, alm, application-lifecycle

The existing ALM implementation has users with DB authentication. How can the LDAP authentication implemented since ALM already have users and this will result in conflict while importing LDAP user list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While importing we will have option as Merge / Skip. If we select Merge then the ID will be merged and no conflicts will arise.